# Callback when web page download completes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

When the user click on a tab in a web page, the tab opens and its corresponding page downloads from the server.

I want to add some UI in this page through JavaScript or jQuery. I know how I can add this but problem is if I execute my JavaScript function for adding UI on click of the tab, it does not work because the corresponding page has not been downloaded yet.

Basically, what I want to know such function that is called when the page completely downloads.

Comment: can you elaborate on "its corresponding page downloads from the server"? What are you doing? Using `$.ajax()`?

Comment: yes, the page downloads asynchronously using ajax

Comment: That still isn't telling us much, if you're using jQuery's `$.ajax()` then you must have to DO something to get that content in the page. You really have to give some info here as to what you're doing (ie: code).

Comment: the existing code do not use jquery, it makes ajax request using javascript. When the tab is clicked, a request is sent to server and the its content which is some div elements download from the server

Answer (score 1):

Have you used JQuery success ?? success handler will be called only after your response is ready.
Try this :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    //Do the stuff here, hence downloading has been completed and response from server is ready
    $(this).addUI("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in the body of your page..

```
<body onload="init()">

</body>
```

Basically your calling your `init function` -- which initiates all the other functions which you want only after the body of the webpage is loaded..

Comment: actually, the new html page does not downloads, only a set of div tag downloads asynchronusly

Comment: it's really hard to guess these things when you give us no info. provide a link, a jsfiddle, or source code

Comment: @vikas provide your code.. hard to guess what your doing.. if your doing it over ajax -- there something called as `onreadystatechange` event -- which change the `readyState` -- so,once that ready state is `4` or `100` you can add your js there.. i.e,`if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //do whatever you want here with xmlhttp.responseText;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I have face this problem too.. Problem here is your content is not yet available before you could work on it.
any reference you give will result in returning *Null*
The solution can be .bind() & [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

suppose this is your dynamic content

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another element</div>');
```

you can bind the element by,

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {  
 // Bound handler called.  
});
```

or register it for live content, by

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {  
// Live handler called.  
});
```

when no longer needed, you may unsubscribe the event on dynamic content by **.die()**
you may also find **.delegate()** & **undelegate()** useful as there are little issues with .live() & .die(). 
Check http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/ for choosing the one you need for your application.
Remember not to forget you ensure that content is loaded by ajax success as programmer_1 here, mentioned.
Good luck :)
Any further clarifications pls comment.